Is upgrading composer is only option here?
I am new to development and I am working on a laravel project on Hostinger hosting. I was trying to run
composer install
But it shows error that I need to upgrade it to composer 2. I don't know if that's safe or will update other packages or show some version errors for other packages.
Should I go for upgrading composer or is there some other work around?
This image contains error
I am running only
composer install

Put the error, please

Sorry! error image description needs changing. I have added image description of error

Please post text as text here, not links to images of text.

Image upload is allowed by stackoverflow. Its stack overlow image link

We still prefer to read text as text.

Composer 2 was released in October 2020 and I don't recall that it had any backward incompatible change, so I can't figure out why bother at all with version 1. Also, I'm not sure of what benefit you get by running Composer right in your hosting account as opposed to doing it in your own computer, unless you want to test in Production.

Did you read the error message after all? "You should upgrade to Composer 2" - pretty obvious hint :) Also, what's the point in running composer install on any other machine than your own or the deployment server?

In Hostinger, you don't need to upgrade composer to use the composer version 2 as it is already installed there. You just need to use it as composer2 instead of composer. So, solution will be only to use:
composer2 install

It will work fine.
For reference look into this link provided by Hostinger:
https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/5792082-how-to-solve-common-composer-issues
